# Why do Mio and her friends seem to all wear different uniforms?

Tags: culture, requiem-for-the-phantom

Mio, who is a student at Reiji and Ellen's school, is introduced in episode 20. It quickly becomes apparent that Mio's friends all wear different uniforms. This is most obvious in ep. 22, where we see a photo of Mio with Sanae and Ellen, after which Hirono, Sanae, and Ellen appear.

[image: Mio with Sanae and Ellen]

[image: Hirono, Sanae, Ellen]

Why do the female students not have a standardised uniform? I have never seen such an egregious case of this. Other examples of differing uniforms are much easier to explain, and none of the reasons there seem applicable to *Phantom*.

- In *Sailor Moon*, Rei is a transfer student and wears her old school uniform. She claims to have been unable to find a new one in her size. No one else wears anything different.
- In *Kare Kano*, students do not all wear the same cookie-cutter uniform, but it is explained in the manga that the school offers a variety of styles for students to wear. It is also very clear that ultimately, these uniform combinations can form a coherent image for the school. In contrast, it is hard to imagine that these girls' uniforms from *Requiem for the Phantom* come from the same school.
- In *Kill la Kill*, everyone except for the student council and Ryuuko seem to wear the same uniform. The student council and Ryuuko have been set apart from the other students, so it is not unreasonable that they should dress differently.

Answer (score 1):

The school may have different uniforms for each class. This seems rather unlikely for the same reason you ruled out reason 2. In [Tari Tari](https://myanimelist.net/anime/13333/Tari_Tari) for example the girls in the music program have a dress while the other girls have skirt and shirt and tie.

It is possible that the school doesn't mandate a uniform but the girls decide to wear something uniform-like anyway because wearing a uniform at highschool is part of the culture. Out of universe it also helps establish that the setting has moved to japan.

Comment: The school does seem to have a uniform though at least for male students, which would make me assume that there also ought to be one for female students. (Reiji wears the same uniform as his friend, and from what I remember it doesn’t seem inconsistent with the background characters.)

Comment: Not all schools have a uniform policy. In those that don't, girls tend to wear what is called a lot of girls wear what is called "[nanchatte seifuku](https://japadventure.com/nanchatte-seifuku)" (なんちゃって制服) which are "fake" school uniforms that are more fashionable and cute. School uniforms are a big deal in Japan as a fashion statement for school age students, for better and for worse. The male student might not care much about fashion and wear more muted designs. Their school may have basic guidelines but no set requirement that may differ by gender.